# How to build eclipse plugin via commandline

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, command-line

I need to integrate a existing Eclipse plugin project into our build factory. I compiled the plugin with javac and created a jar file, but it is not working as plugin for Eclipse. I receive a lot of exception "unable to load class".
Google return mostly Maven but I can not change the existing build process.

Does anybody has an idea what is required to do this?

Comment: Did you include the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file in your jar?

Comment: Yes, it is in the jar

Comment: Just guessing now, but a few things to check. Make sure you create the jar with something like the jar tool rather than winzip or it might not include directory entries. Check your manifest file is in the META-INF foleder within the jar and that it contains all the OSGi headers. If you have a plugin.xml check that it's in the root of the jar.

Comment: Problem solved, missed to add the specified manifest to the jar command.

Answer (score 0):

put your created jar in `eclipse\plugins` folder and restart eclips.

Comment: I tried it with eclipse/plugins and with eclipse/dropins, still not working. I try the same with the plugin exported as eclipse plugin and it is working.